# AngularJS executing promises in turn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I need to be able to execute a series of asynchronous events in turn, but the execution of each depends on the result of the last. Is there anyway to achieve this dynamically? Consider the following code as an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
$scope.queries = [
    {
        id: 1,
        action: function(){
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             Service.something($.param(someData)).$promise.then(function(response){
                  deferred.resolve(response);
             }, function(error){
                  deferred.reject(error);
             });
             return deferred.promise;
        }
    },{
        id: 2,
        action: function(){
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             Service.something($.param(someData)).$promise.then(function(response){
                  deferred.resolve(response);
             }, function(error){
                  deferred.reject(error);
             });
             return deferred.promise;
        }
    },{
        id: 3,
        action: function(){
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             Service.something($.param(someData)).$promise.then(function(response){
                  deferred.resolve(response);
             }, function(error){
                  deferred.reject(error);
             });
             return deferred.promise;
        }
    },
];
$scope.stop = false;

angular.forEach($scope.queries, function(query) {
    if ($scope.stop === false) {
         query.action().then(function(result){
             //Everything is fine so we can continue to the next request
         }, function(error) {
            //This request produced an error so we need to stop
            $scope.stop = true;
            //Display error here
         });
    }
});
```

The main problem is how do I get the forEach to wait for the result of each action before it continues to the next?

Any help in understand this and finding a solution would be great. The only solution I can think of is manually chaining the three requests using chained .then()'s.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when I want to run things in sequence, I use a for or foreach loop, promises are no different and require no magic, you just have to specify the continuation with `.then`

```
var promise = $q.when();

angular.forEach($scope.queries, function(query) {
    promise = promise.then(function(){ 
        // no need for scope.stop, a rejection will act like a throw and it'll
        // stop executing code
        return query.action();
    });
});
```

If you want to know when they're all done, you can do:

```
promise.then(function(){
    alert("All actions done!");
});
```

Note, your service code has the [deferred anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern), you can convert code that looks like:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
Service.something($.param(someData)).$promise.then(function(response){
    deferred.resolve(response);
}, function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

To simply do:

```
return Service.something($.param(someData)).$promise;
```

Comment: Yeap! Worked as expected <3